# Eclipse: similar plugin to emacs ace-jump-mode?

Tags: java, eclipse

Currently I use emacs but sometimes it takes a long time to configure it. I would like to use eclipse, but what I miss there is jumping around. Does emacs have some plugin which is working like ace-jump-mode: http://emacsrocks.com/e10.html?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one from my github. https://github.com/whunmr/emacsIDEAsForEclipse/blob/master/acejump_1.0.0.201608252253.jar

source code is also available in the same repo.